# openmp parallel for schedule construct giving different answers for ever few program runs

Tags: c, openmp

I am trying to use openmp work sharing constructs. The code shared is a simpler example of what's going wrong with my bigger openmp code. I'm assigning values to an integer matrix, printing the matrix element values, initialising them to 0 and repeating it in a 't' loop. I'm counting the number of times the value assignments (done by parallel for) fail through the integer 'p'. p is supposed to be 0 if the code is correct, but it gives me different answers for different runs, so the work construct is failing somewhere. I had to run it around 12 times before I got the first wrong value of p as output (1, 2, 3, etc.)

The barrier directives in the code aren't really necessary, I was getting different values of p without it and thought an explicit barrier would help but I was wrong. This is the code:

```
    #define NRA 10                 /* number of rows in matrix A */
    #define NCA 10                 /* number of columns in matrix A */

    int main()
    {
        int i, j, ir, p = 0, t; 
        int *a; 
        a = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int)*NRA*NCA);

        omp_set_num_threads(5);

        for(t=0;t<100000;t++)
        {
            #pragma omp barrier
            #pragma omp parallel for schedule (static,2) collapse(2)
            for(i=0;i<NRA;i++)
            {
                for(j=0;j<NCA;j++)
                { 
                    ir=j*NRA+i; 
                    a[ir] = 1; 
                }
            }

            #pragma omp single
            {
                for(i=0;i<NRA;i++)
                {
                    for(j=0;j<NCA;j++)
                    { 
                        ir=j*NRA+i; 
                        if(a[ir] != 1)
                        { 
                            p += 1;
                        } 
                    }
                }
            }

            #pragma omp parallel for schedule (static,2) collapse(2)
            for(i=0;i<NRA;i++)
            {
                for(j=0;j<NCA;j++)
                { 
                    ir=j*NRA+i; 
                    a[ir] = 0; 
                }
            }

            # pragma omp barrier
        }//end t 

        printf("p is %d\n",p);
    }
```

This is the bigger code, and I don't think the race condition is an issue because I declared all variables outside parallel loop shared and all other variables locally inside the parallel loop. Any suggestions would be helpful!

```
    #define NRA 10                 /* number of rows in matrix A */
    #define NCA 10                 /* number of columns in matrix A */
    #define NCB 10                  /* number of columns in matrix B */

    void matrixcalc (double *ad, double *bd, double *cd, int chunkd);
    void printresults (double *cd, int chunkd);
    void printrep (double *cd, int chunkd);

    int main () 
    {
        int nthreads, chunk, p = 0;
        double *a,*b,*c;   
        a = (double*)malloc(NRA*NCA*sizeof(double)); 
        if(a==NULL) 
            printf("ho\n"); 
        b = (double*)malloc(NCA*NCB*sizeof(double));
        c = (double*)malloc(NRA*NCB*sizeof(double));

        omp_set_num_threads(5);

        chunk = 2;                    /* set loop iteration chunk size */
        int ir3, i1, j1;

        /*** Spawn a parallel region explicitly scoping all variables ***/
        int t, tmax = 100000;
        for(t=0;t<tmax;t++)
        {
            #pragma omp parallel shared(a,b,c,nthreads,chunk,t,tmax) 
            { 
                int tid = omp_get_thread_num(); 
                int i, j, ir;
                if (tid == 0)
                {
                    nthreads = omp_get_num_threads();
                    // printf("Starting matrix multiple example with %d threads\n",nthreads);
                    // printf("Initializing matrices...\n");
                }

                /*** Initialize matrices ***/
                #pragma omp for schedule (static, chunk) collapse(2)
                for (i=0; i<NRA; i++)
                {   
                    for (j=0; j<NCA; j++)
                    { 
                        ir =j*NRA+i; 
                        a[ir]= 1.0; 
                    }
                }
                #pragma omp for schedule (static, chunk) collapse(2)
                for (i=0; i<NCA; i++)
                {   
                    for (j=0; j<NCB; j++)
                    {  
                        ir = j*NCA+i; 
                        b[ir] = 1.0;
                    }
                }
                #pragma omp for schedule (static, chunk) collapse(2)
                for (i=0; i<NRA; i++)
                {    
                    for (j=0; j<NCB; j++)
                    { 
                        ir=j*NRA+i; 
                        c[ir]= 0.0;
                    }
                }
                /*** Do matrix multiply sharing iterations on outer loop ***/
                /*** Display who does which iterations for demonstration purposes ***/

                matrixcalc(a,b,c,chunk);
                if(t!=tmax-1)
                {
                    #pragma omp for schedule (static, chunk) collapse(2)
                    for(i=0;i<NRA;i++)
                    {    
                        for(j=0;j<NCB;j++)
                        {
                            ir=j*NRA+i;
                            c[ir]=0.0;
                        }
                    } 
                }
            }//end parallel region

            for(i1=0;i1<NRA;i1++)
            {
                for(j1=0;j1<NCB;j1++)
                {
                    ir3=j1*NRA+i1; 
                    if(c[ir3]!=12.20000&&c[ir3]!=0.0)
                    {
                        printf("%lf\n",c[ir3]);
                        p+=1;
                    } 
                }
           }  

       }//end t 
       printf("finalp\t%d\n",p);
       for(i1=0;i1<NRA;i1++)
       {
           for(j1=0;j1<NCB;j1++)
           { 
               ir3=j1*NRA+i1;
               printf("%lf\t",c[ir3]);
           }
           printf("\n");
       } 
   }   

   void matrixcalc (double *a, double *b, double *c, int chunk)
   {
       int i,j,k,ir,ir1,ir2;

       //printf("Thread %d starting matrix multiply...%d\n",tid,chunk);
       double r = 1.0;
       #pragma omp for schedule (static, chunk) collapse(3)

       for (i=0; i<NRA; i++)    
       {
           for(j=0; j<NCB; j++)  
           {     
               for (k=0; k<NCA; k++)
               {
                   ir=j*NRA+i; 
                   ir1=k*NRA+i; 
                   ir2=j*NCA+k; 
                   c[ir] += a[ir1] * b[ir2];
               }
           }
       }
       #pragma omp for schedule (static, chunk) collapse(2)
       for(i=0;i<NRA;i++)
       {
           for(j=0;j<NCB;j++)
           { 
               ir=j*NRA+i;
               c[ir]+=r*2.0;
           }
       }
       #pragma omp single
       {  
           double h; 
           h = 0.1;
           h = 2.0*h; 
           for(i=0;i<NRA;i++)
           {
               for(j=0;j<NCB;j++)
               {
                   ir=j*NRA+i;
                   c[ir]+=h;
               }
           }
       }
```

Comment: Those barriers are totally unnecessary because they are outside a parallel section (no parallelism is created). In addition, `omp single` and `omp for` produce an implicit barrier at the end of the block, so in any case it would be redundant. Consider using a parallel (only) construct outside `t` loop, and then use plain `omp for` and `omp single` in the rest of constructs. In addition, change the order of the `i` and `j` loops to access `a[]` elements sequentially (improves cache locality).

Comment: I understand about the barriers, and I've taken note of the other suggestion ( though I didn't understand why! ) . I tried putting the parallel construct outside the t loop, and the code took much longer to give the output, I had to kill the program.

Comment: Regarding your error - I'm not going to make a full review of such as substantially changed question, but the call to `matrixcalc(a,b,c,chunk);` from within a parallel region is asking for trouble.

Comment: I understand but the code I  eventually have to write has many subroutines like matrixcalc. So I need to make something like this weeork. The trouble is with matrixcalc, I checked, it works fine without it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is a race condition on `ir`. Since it is defined outside of the loop, it is implicitly `shared`. You could force it to be `private`, but it is better to declare variables as locally as possible. That makes reasoning about OpenMP code much easier:

```
#pragma omp parallel for schedule (static,2) collapse(2)
for(int i=0;i<NRA;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<NCA;j++)
    { 
        int ir = j*NRA+i; 
        a[ir] = 1; 
    }
}
```

As commented by Jorge Bellón, there are other issues in your code with respect to redundant barriers and efficiency.

Comment: thanks! In the similar but bigger code, I've declared ir, i, and j to be private so there is no race condition I could immediately spot, but this worked on  the code I put up here.

Comment: On the update, you have a similar problem as @Zulan pointed out. In this case it happens with `ir3` variable.

Comment: I believe that `ir3` is only used outside the parallel region. But I can only repeat myself, by default **declare variables as locally as possible**, and initialize them on the same line. You save yourself much trouble.

Comment: It isn't ir3, I checked y defining it in the for loops it's used in, and I only use it outside the parallel region. I don't think it's a variable declaration problem here, though I'll keep that in mind.